# Value-Carrying Exceptions in SML

Tags: exception, tree, sml

My homework is to implement a program that takes a function and binary tree and outputs a list of integers from the binary tree that fulfill the function (example: the function returns true if the number is even, thus the program's output will be a list of even integers).

I have the code here:

```
    datatype 'a tree = Empty | Node of ('a tree  * int * 'a tree) 

    fun collect (p, Empty) = []
    |collect (p, Node (L, x, R)) =
    if (p x) then x :: (collect (p, L) @ collect (p, R))
    else
    collect (p, L) @ collect (p, R);
```

which works fine, but the assignment REQUIRES I implement this function with exceptions. We are supposed to use value-carrying functions, but my code just won't work:

```
    fun collect (p, Empty) = []
      | collect (p, (Node(L, x, R))) = 
        if (p x) then (raise FoundSoFar [x])
        else 
            (collect (p, L))@(collect (p, R))
    handle FoundSoFar x => x @ (collect (p, L))@(collect (p, R))
```

which compiles properly, but when I try the test code given by the teacher:

```
    val L = Node (Node (Empty, 2, Empty), 5, Node (Empty, 6, Empty));
    val R = Node (Empty, 12, Empty);
    val T = Node (Node (L, 7, Node (Empty, 8, Empty)), 11, R);

    val r = collect ((fn x => (x mod 2) = 0) , T);
```

I just get an uncaught exception error...
I either need help understanding whats wrong with my code, how to fix it, and\or how to properly implement value-carrying exceptions in SML, anything will help, thanks.

Comment: Which exception did you get? And isn't your FoundSoFar a value-carrying exception?

Comment: It compiles, it just doesnt work. It actually says uncaught foundsofar exception.

Comment: Consider for a moment what you're doing: You're looking for an element that satisfies `p` in the left and right subtrees. If you find one, an exception is thrown, which you catch, and then you do the same search again. So, naturally you'll get the same exception thrown again.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. The exception you get already carries a value. Maybe your real question is how to get to the value for debugging? Well, you could just wrap a 'handle' around the expression defining 'r' (which is the one that throws) and pattern match it.

Comment: The r is just a test case the teacher gave us, it's not to be changed. I need the end result of the code to give me each element of the tree that satisfies the function p and it has to be carried by exceptions, those are the homework's parameters.

Comment: Yes, but there is nothing wrong with changing the code temporarily for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code doesn't make sense:

```
        (collect (p, L))@(collect (p, R))
handle FoundSoFar x => x @ (collect (p, L))@(collect (p, R))
```

If the `handle` part is run, that means `(collect (p, L))@(collect (p, R))` threw an exception. But then what do you do when you handle it? You evaluate that exact same expression *again* (as part of the right side of the handle expression). So naturally, this evaluation will fail and throw the exact same exception again, kind of like this:

```
(collect (p, L))@(collect (p, R)) handle FoundSoFar x => raise FoundSoFar x
```

So in the end, it is as if you never caught the exception in the first place:

```
(collect (p, L))@(collect (p, R))
```

You probably wanted to catch the exception, and then do something useful with the value you caught, but *not* run the exact same expression that caused the exception to start with.

P.S. another unrelated issue in your code you want to consider is precedence. `handle` has higher precedence than `if-then-else`